# What is wrong with this code ? Why isn't it working the way I hoped it would..?

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

Bear with me guys.. Im new to JavaScript AND StackOverflow...

Here is my problem :

I have created a simple piece of code, with 3 buttons that should change a text (innerHTML) when pressed... but it's not working.. :-(

What am I doing wrong ?

I have checked W3Schools for clues.. but no dice..

````
<head>
  <title>JavaScript Table</title>
  <style>
    body{
        text-align: center;
        font-family: arial;
    }
  </style>
        <script>
            function red(){
                document.getElementById("tekst").innerHTML = "Red";
            }
            function green(){
                document.getElementById("tekst").innerHTML = "Green";
            }
            function blue(){
                document.getElementById("tekst").innerHTML = "Blue";
            }
        </script>
</head>
<body>
        <h2 id="tekst">Color</h2>
        <button onsubmit="red()">Red</button>
        <button onsubmit="green()">Green</button>
        <button onsubmit="blue()">Blue</button>     
</body>
</html>```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `onsubmit` to `onclick`. You can also add an event in the script:

HTML:

```
<h2 id="text">Color</h2>
<button id="red">Red</button>
<button id="green">Green</button>
<button id="blue">Blue</button>`
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById("red").addEventListener("click", () => 
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "RED")

document.getElementById("green").addEventListener("click", () => 
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "GREEN")

document.getElementById("blue").addEventListener("click", () => 
document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "BLUE")
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change `onsubmit` to `onclick`.

You can shorten the code by using `addEventListener`. You can create array of texts and use `forEach` loop to add listeners to buttons to change the text to the element of array at particular index.

```js
const arr = ["Red","Green","Blue"]
const h2 = document.querySelector('#tekst');
document.querySelectorAll('button').forEach((x,i) => {
  x.addEventListener('click',() => h2.innerHTML = arr[i])
})
```

```html
<head>
  <title>JavaScript Table</title>
  <style>
    body{
        text-align: center;
        font-family: arial;
    }
  </style>
        <script>
            
        </script>
</head>
<body>
        <h2 id="tekst">Color</h2>
        <button>Red</button>
        <button>Green</button>
        <button>Blue</button>     
</body>
```

Comment: Owwww of course !  
Thanks for helping out a newbie  :-)   And so fast !
I really appreciate it !

Comment: @AlexvanWinkel You are welcome. Consider accepting the answer if you are satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <button onclick="red()">Red</button>
   <button onclick="green()">Green</button>
   <button onclick="blue()">Blue</button>
```

Please replace with `onclick` instead of `onsubmit`.